# Sending whisper messages over testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper, shh

I managed to setup a private blockchain and send whisper messages between my clients. Now, i want to accomplish the very same thing over either the mainnet or one of the testnets.

But it seems that no node i ever connect to in any of the networks has ssh enabled. My messages are not coming through.

Does anyone know of a working example of whisper messages delivered through the main- or one of the testnets?

I'm using geth for my experiment, if thats of any value

Comment: Can you tell me how you got your private blockchain with whisper working.. got a simple demo for me? Really want to try it out but can't figure.

Comment: @rayray For the setup of the private blockchain, i used 2 VM who shared the same network. I followed this tutorial for setting up the private blockchain: https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0

After that, i connected the nodes by executing "geth attach" and used "admin.addPeer(<enodeUrl>). You can see your enodeUrl by executing admin.nodeInfo.
Then, i started geth with the arguments "geth --ws --wsapi 'web3,eth,shh' --wsorigins "*" -shh" and opened up the node console.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-shh.html#post

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no incentive to route whisper messages through the main network, hence the majority of nodes will not have it enabled.